# The pod's /etc/resolv.conf does not reflect the changes on the host

Tags: domain-name-system, kubernetes, k3s

When my pod's `dnsPolicy` is set to `Default` it picks up the DNS servers from the host's `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` (as configured by the `resolvConf` flag in Kubernetes) and stores them in `/etc/resolv.conf` inside the pod. This is normal Kubernetes behaviour.

But when `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` changes on the host machine, in my case, when it gets a DNS server from the DHCP server, the pod's `/etc/resolv.conf` does not get updated automatically. I have to restart the pod to make sure the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` reflects that of the host's `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

Is there a Kubernetes flag or some sort to keep them in sync?

Answer (score 0):

As described on the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#introduction), you can use flag --resolv-conf to point the configuration to a valid DNS config file. You can follow steps as describon this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549954) to modify your DNS configuration.

If think that configuring configmap of the [CoreDNS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns) should do an  uncomplicated changes since you can point a particular DNS server to resolve domain request even you do sudden changes on the DNS server.